# Avoid delayed patching

Tags: python, unit-testing, caching, mocking, monkeypatching

I'm working on a Python project where I use `diskcache.Cache.memoize` for caching. I want to write unit tests for my code, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly mock `diskcache.Cache.memoize` using pytest without being delayed in my mocks.

Here's a simplified version of my module:

```py
# my_module.py
import diskcache

cache = diskcache.Cache('/path/to/my/local/cache')

@cache.memoize(expire=3600)
def expensive_function(argument):
    # Expensive calculation here
    return result
```

I want to write unit tests for `expensive_function` where I can test the caching behavior on and off via pytest.

I have mocked diskcache.Cache in `conftest.py` like so:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest
import unittest.mock
import diskcach


class MockCache:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __call__(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):
        return fun

    def memoize(fun, *args, **kwargs):
        return fun


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def default_mock_memoize(monkeypatch, pytestconfig):
    if not pytestconfig.getoption("--cache"):
        monkeypatch.setattr(diskcache, "Cache", MockCache)


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--cache",
        action="store_true",
        default=False,
        help=(
            "Enable caching for tests. Careful: This will disable the test coverage "
            "of the cached code if the return value is in cache."
        ),
    )
```

This works technically but is too late since it leaves the decorated `expensive_function` in the hands of the unmocked diskcache.Cache.
**How can I achieve that `diskcache.Cache` is mocked before collection?**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? If it's the cache, you can test it with a less expensive function. If it's `expensive_function`, don't mock the cache: use it as it is intended.

Comment: I want to test `expensive_function`. I don't get the 'use it as it is intended' part. If I test `expensive_function`, this will only be tested once and later return the same thing over and over again.

Comment: It will be tested once *per unique argument*. Why do you need it to actually execute multiple times per argument?

Comment: I want to run the same test again for the next development cycle. I don't want to clear the cache after tests since it would interfere with the app. Also I will use the same function with the same inputs in part of another test since things build on top of that.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the "disk" in "disk cache". But as you aren't specifying a path when you create the cache, isn't it using a temporary directory that won't be reused by the next run?

Comment: @chepner Yes, that is though a shortcoming in my question. Thanks I will correct that.

Comment: OK, I think you want to make the path to the disk cache *configurable*, rather than hard-coding it. Then you don't need to mock anything. It could be as simple as `cp = os.getenv('CACHE_PATH', '/path/to/my/local/cache'); cache = diskcache.Cache(cp)`. Then you simply set `CACHE_PATH` in your test environment to use something else. (If it's not set at all, you use your hard-coded default.)

Comment: Better yet, though, design the module to leave the location of the cache entirely up to whoever *imports* the module, maybe by having a `my_module.set_cache` function that has to be called before anything else in the module can be used. (The `logging` module does something similar with `logging.basicConfig`, though its module-level functions do some "emergency" configuration if they don't detect any explicit configuration having been done.)

Comment: Thanks for further thinking about it. I have it non-hard coded (via hydra config (extendable by the user), just removed it for this MWE. I will give your proposed solution a try. Thanks!